how to scale a window with Xlib?
How to scale a window with Xlib ? I have search it in search engines. And almost all answer is to resize window. chatgpt answer me that scale with opengl. but its demo not work at all.

You cannot, X11 doesn't scale anything.

Assuming you mean draw at other than 1:1 pixel scale, you can't in plain Xlib. XCopyArea and XPutImage have no parameters that allow the destination width and height to be different from the source.
The XRender extension can rescale images by assigning a transformation matrix to a destination. There's an example at
https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/misc/x11-composite-tutorial/
Much easier if you use a 2D drawing library such as Qt Painter or Cairo instead.

It sounds like if only use Xlib, can only write own scaling algorithm using the Xlib image API. Or pass the window ID to the 2D graphics library to call the scaling API (because I am writing WM and cannot use the 2D graphics library directly).

The XRender extension has been around for over a decade, so I would expect most modern systems with Xlib would also have XRender
